# keyword memory in event definition causes error when compile

Tags: solidity

Here is an event defined in a contract. However it throws an error when compiling:

```
pragma "^0.7.0";

    event _tradeComplete(address _poster, string memory  _posterItemName, uint256 _posterItemID, address _bidder,  string memory _bidderItemName, uint256 _bidderItemID, uint256 _value);  //keyword memory throws error
```

However the error disappears if `memory` is removed. Why `memory` can't be used here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add data location for variables when declaring a event. Remove the `memory` keyword from your events, this should work:

```
event _tradeComplete(address _poster, string _posterItemName, uint256 _posterItemID, address _bidder, string _bidderItemName, uint256 _bidderItemID, uint256 _value);
```

Comment: Do you have some reading for event param without memory? I understand briefly about storage vs memory. In my function params, memory is used for string and it seems to be reasonable to pass a pointer to a function. Here event doesn't take it the same way.